# Updating data used by a shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I have a relatively simple problem. I want to build a shiny app (and publish it via shinyapps.io) that loads a csv file which is updated daily. Since it takes quite a lot of time to update the data (around 30 min, I am retriving some twitter data using `rtweet`) I would like to run a separate script (`update_data.R`) every day that would update the `my_data.csv` file (which is loaded in the shiny server function) so that the app is not interrupted.

What is the easiest way to update the csv file daily without interrupting the app? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to have a script run to update a database, files, run a script, scrape web information and minute that data -- it depends on your method of deployment and desire of function. You can have a local instance of the machine you are on and run a chronjob. You can use GitHub runners to simulate activity or cascading tasks on a timer, there are options on hosting platforms like digital ocean // please specify needs more for a clear answer  -- use case and scope are helpful

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I would like to publish an app via shinyapps.io which would display a few word clouds summarising some tweets. I would like to extract around 30000 tweets daily and save them as a csv file, which would be read by the app. Currently, I am thinking of running a cronjob that would connect to the API and extract tweets daily, save them on MySQL and the app would load data directly from MySQL. Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: Hello, yes I think that stack sounds like a good way to achieve your goal, I would say that if you don't need to reference old tweets and aren't building a database of tweets that you could just keep the 30,000 tweets in an in memory database, either RSQLite or even just in the cache (disk/memory) that would have a max file age of 24 hours and will be updated with the new data...how many users are you expecting?

Comment: Difficult to say, but I wouldn't expect more than a couple hundreds per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested Deployment: (Daily Database Renewal)

```
library(rtweet)
library(cachem)
library(shiny)
library(cronR)
```

If you are hosting locally,

1. Have your shinyapps.io website spin up and be online when you make `rtweet` queries to scrape data, collect infor and store as an R object in your env.
2. Use `cachem` to create a cache in mem/disk (depending on size of df returned/amount of info wanting to store)
3. Refer to this `maxAge = 86400` created cache to keep your `rtweet` data and perform word cloud analysis on these datasets
4. Enjoy your published data pipeline!